# TCL C API, printing Tcl object

Tags: c++, c, tcl

I need simple C/C++ program which creates a `Tcl_Obj`, set some value to it and prints that value. I need to see how it can be done using C API. Here is what I have done so far.

```
#include <tcl.h>

int main() {
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp(); 

    Tcl_Obj* tclObj = new Tcl_NewObj();

    // setting tclObj some value
    // printing it using something like this Tcl_PrintVariable(tclObj);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're advised to call `Tcl_FindExecutable` before creating an interpreter or calling any other Tcl API functions (pass `argv[0]` or `NULL`) as this, among other things, initialises Tcl's memory management subsystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*set value */
Tcl_SetIntObj(tclObj, 3);
/*print value*/
int i;
Tcl_GetIntFromObj(interp, tclObj, &i);
printf("Value: %d\r\n", i);
```

Also better to check return value of Tcl_GetIntFromObj().
Refer to this page - [Tcl reference manual](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/IntObj.html)